# what does multiple class references in css do?

Tags: css

So obviously this question will need a bit more explaining.

what is the difference between this:

```
.class1 .class2 {blahblah}
```

this:

```
.class1, .class2 {blahblah}
```

and this:

```
.class1 > .class2 {blahblah}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the differences. I'd like this to be explained in as much detail as possible. I haven't found anything anwhere that breaks it down to me in the way I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.class1 .class2 {blahblah}` affects element where class2 is ancestor to element having .class1

`.class1, .class2 {blahblah}` this means that css rules affects element having class1 or class2

`.class1 > .class2 {blahblah}` this means that .class1 needs to be parent of class2.

**Examples:**

```
<elementA class="class1">
  <elementB class="class2"></elementB>
</elementA>
```

Element B is child to Element A so both `.class1 .class2 {}` and `.class1 > .class2 {}` definition will affect it.

```
<elementA class="class1">
  <elementC>
      <elementB class="class2"></elementB>
  </elementC>
</elementA>
```

In this case only `.class1 .class2 {}` will be correct because there is no direct relation parent->child between element B and A.

`.class1 .class2 {}`

and last one

```
<elementA class="class1"></elementA>
<elementB class="class2"></elementB>
```

only `.class1, .class2 {}` will work because there is no parent/child/ancestor relation between these elements.

You may find [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer cleared my confusion right up.

Answer (score 0):

1. **`.class1 .class2 {}`**

This selects `.class2` which is a child of `.class1`

---

2. **`.class1, .class2 {}`**

This selects `.class1` as well as `.class2`

---

3. **`.class1 > .class2 {}`**

This selects `.class2` which is immediately next to `.class1`

---

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.case1 .class1 .class2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.case2 .class1, .case2 .class2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.case3 .class1 > .class2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

pre {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="case1">
  <strong>Case 1: <pre>.class1 .class2</pre></strong>
  <div class="class1">Class1
    <div class="class2">Class2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="case2">
  <strong>Case 2: <pre>.class1, .class2</pre></strong>
  <div class="class1">Class1
    <div class="class2">Class2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="case3">
  <strong>Case 3: <pre>.class1 > .class2</pre></strong>
  <div class="class1">Class1
    <div class="class2">Class2</div>
    <div class="class3">
      <div class="class2">Class2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at three different selectors in CSS:

- `.class1 .class2 {}` is the descendant selector - the styles will apply to any `.class2` element which is a descendant of a `.class1` element (no matter how many levels down)
- `.class1, .class2 {}` is the multiple element selector - the styles will apply to any `.class1` element *and* any `.class2` element
- `.class1 > .class2 {}` is the direct descendant selector - the styles will apply to any `.class2` element which is an *immediate* child descendant of a `.class1` element (if it is a grandchild or a great-grandchild, the styles *won't* apply)

There are many other selectors. Here are a few:

- `.class1 + .class2 {}` is the immediate sibling selector - the styles will apply to any `.class2` element which is an *immediately adjacent* sibling of a `.class1` element (if it is a non-consecutive sibling, the styles *won't* apply)
- `.class1 ~ .class2 {}` is the subsequent sibling selector - the styles will apply to any `.class2` element which is a subsequent sibling of a `.class1` element (no matter how many siblings later it appears)
- `.class1.class2 {}` is the simultaneous selector - the styles will apply to an element only if it is both a `.class1` element and a `.class2` element (eg. `style="class1 class2"`)

**Examples:**

```css
div {border: 1px solid rgb(191,191,191); padding:6px;}
.class1 {border: 1px solid rgb(0,127,0);}
.class1, .class2 {font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
.class1 .class2 {font-weight: bold;}
.class1 > .class2 {color:rgb(0,0,255);}
.class1 ~ .class2 {font-style: italic;}
.class1 + .class2 { color:rgb(255,0,0);}
.class1.class2 {text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li style="border: 1px solid rgb(191,191,191); padding:6px;">a div has a border around it</li>
<li style="border: 1px solid rgb(0,127,0); padding:6px;">a .class1 has a green border around it</li>
<li>.class1, .class2 is <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">sans-serif</span></li>
<li>.class1 .class2 is <strong>bold</strong></li>
<li>.class1 > .class2 is <span style="color:rgb(0,0,255);">blue</span></li>
<li>.class1 ~ .class2 is <em>italic</em></li>
<li>.class1 + .class2 is <span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">red</span></li>
<li>.class1.class2 is <u>underlined</u></li>
</ul>

<div class="class1">
<p>I am a paragraph with no class. The 5 paragraphs below are all .class2.</p>
  
<p class="class2">I am .class1 > .class2 and .class1 .class2</p>
<div>
<p class="class2">I am just .class1 .class2</p>
</div>
</div>

<p class="class2">I am .class1 + .class2 and .class1 ~ .class2</p>
<p class="class2">I am just .class1 ~ .class2</p>
<p class="class1 class2">I am .class1 ~ .class2 and  .class1.class2</p>

<div>
<p class="class1 class2">I am just .class1.class2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [great game](https://flukeout.github.io/) that can teach you what each of those selectors does.

The space is the `descendant` selector. It says select all class2 that are a descendants of a class1.

The comma is an OR meaning select class1 or class2.

The > is the `direct descendant` meaning select all class2 that have a direct parent which is class1.

Answer (score 0):

```
.class1 .class2 {rules}
```

Selects all elements with .class2 inside all elements with .class1

```
.class1, .class2 {rules}
```

Selects all elements with .class1 and all elements with .class2

```
.class1 > .class2 {rules}
```

Selects just child elements with .class2 where the parents is a element with .class1

Answer (score 0):

`.class1 > .class2` targets the element `.class2` that is a direct child of the element `.class1`

`.class1 .class2` targets the element with `.class2` that is inside an other element with `.class1` no matter if it is it's direct child or not (it can be the child of child on so on).

`.class1, .class2` targets the element with `.class1` and the element with `.class2`.

this is the [reference to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information_Selectors_based_on_relationships) on this topic.